# VisualStateManager.GoToSate() does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visualstatemanager

I am trying to create visual states in my WP8 app. But I can't get it to work, even this simple example. Can anybody spot what is wrong?

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Margin="1,0,-1,0">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="Faded">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ToFade" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Button Content="some text" x:Name="ToFade" />
    <Button Content="Change"
            Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind:

```
    private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        var result = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.ToFade, "Faded", true);
    }
```

It is supposed to animate opacity of the top button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first parameter of `GoToState()` method should be the page itself. Try by calling `GoToState()` as follows:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Faded", true);
```

Comment: I dont think this works, GoToState needs a control as the first argument, LayoutRoot is a FrameworkElement.